# jQuery change() not triggering when pressing space?

Tags: jquery, html-entities

In order to highlight spacing between Chinese characters I've got this code

```
function replaceSpaces(){
    var segmented = $(this).val().replace(/\s/g, "<span>&emsp;</span>");
    $('#preview').html(segmented);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tobesegmented').focus(replaceSpaces);
    $('.tobesegmented').change(replaceSpaces);
});
```

however, it does **NOT** trigger the change when I hit the space bar, only when i add text. Is there a way to trigger the replaceSpaces when a person hit's the space bar?

Bonus: Also, why does `<span>&amp;emsp;</span>` become `<span>&amp;amp;emsp;</span>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`keyup` event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead (or in addition), like this:

```
$('.tobesegmented').bind('focus keyup', replaceSpaces);
```

[`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) can also take multiple event names separated by a space, so illustrating that as well, shaving a bit of code off :)

For the bonus: because it gets HTML encoded for you, as another example, `.text('&')` on an element will actually render `&amp;` in the HTML :)

Comment: note that keyup will fire on non-printing keypresses as well, so (while in this case it's OK) it's sometimes a good idea to filter it to something approximating printables if that's what you're interested in.